# Дан бинарный файл, содержащий коэффициенты квадратных уравнений

Tags: c, массивы, файлы

> Дан бинарный файл вещественных чисел, содержащий коэффициенты квадратных уравнений (A1, B1, С1, A2, B2, С2, …). Создать новый бинарный файл, содержащий вначале три числа N2, N1, N0 — количество в исходном файле уравнений с двумя, одним и нулем действительных корней, далее — значения корней всех уравнений с двумя действительными корнями, а затем значения корней всех уравнений с одним действительным корнем. Допустима работа как с текстовым файлом.

Не могу уйти дальше заполнения первого файла. Как можно считать данные из него таким образом, чтобы получилось уравнение, т.e. чтобы считывалось 3 коэффициента и они отправлялись на свои места?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <windows.h> 
void main() 
{ 
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); 
    int A[100][3];
    int N, m=3; 
    int i, j,k;
    FILE *f=fopen("num.txt","w"), *nf=fopen("rad.txt","w"); 
    if(f==NULL) 
        printf("Не удалось открыть файл"); 
    if(nf==NULL) 
        printf("Не удалось создать файл"); 
    printf("Введите количество уравнений:N="); 
    scanf("%d",&N); 
    for(i=0;i<N;i++) 
    { 
        for(j=0;j<m;j++) 
        { 
            printf("Введите коэффициенты уравнений:",i+1,j+1); 
            scanf("%d",&A[i][j]); 
            fprintf(f,"%d",A[i][j]); 
        } 
    } 

    fclose(f);
    fclose(nf);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Еще один математик. "Не могу уйти дальше заполнения первого файла." - Вам же уже дан файл с коэффициентами. И он двоичный (`"wb"`) - то есть написан `fwrite`-ом, а не `fprintf`-ом. И числа в нем вещественные, а не целые.

Comment: @Igor Допустима работа как с текстовым файлом

Comment: Вы сами не понимаете, что написали... И никто за Вас этого сделать не сможет. Ответьте сами себе хотя бы на два вопроса: 1) Зачем вы объявили два файла (f, nf) но используете только один? Если Вы собирались из одно файла читать, а в другой - писать, то почему у Вас оба файла открыты на ЗАПИСЬ ? Ну, про двоичные файлы Вам уже сказали...

Comment: @Sergey Допустима работа как с текстовым файлом, что писалось выше. Первый файл заполняется коэффициентами, а во втором вычисляются корни, потому они оба открыты для записи. И как я должен использовать второй файл, если не могу понять как отправить туда переменные

Comment: **во втором вычисляются корни** - корни не могут ВЫЧИСЛЯТЬСЯ в файле. В файл можно только ЗАПИСАТЬ результат вычислений.

Comment: **не могу понять как отправить туда переменные** - отправить (я так предполагаю - ЗАПИСАТЬ) можно не переменные, а ЗНАЧЕНИЯ переменных. Способ записи зависит от от вида фала, открытого на запись. Если файл символьный - используйте *fprintf*, если двоичный - *write*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я накидал несколько функций по поводу Вашей проблемы, в частности в функции `readCoefsFromFile`производится считывание коэффициентов из бинарного файла:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
//Максимальное количество уравнений в программе (насколько я понял Вам нельзя работать с динамической памятью)
#define MAX_ARRAY_SIZE 5

// Функция для записи коэффициентов в файл
void writeCoefsToFile(const char* fileName, double coefs[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE][3]) {

    FILE* f = fopen(fileName, "wb");
    if (f) {

        fwrite(coefs, sizeof(double), MAX_ARRAY_SIZE * 3, f);
        fclose(f);
    }
}

// Функция для считывания коэффициентов из файла
void readCoefsFromFile(const char* fileName, double coefs[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE][3]) {

    FILE* f = fopen(fileName, "rb");
    if (f) {

        fread(coefs, sizeof(double), MAX_ARRAY_SIZE * 3, f);
        fclose(f);
    }
}

// Функция для решения квадратных уравнений
int findRoots(double a, double b, double c, double* x1, double* x2) {

    double d = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if ((int)d == 0) {

        *x1 = -b/(2 * a);
        return 1;
    } else if (d > 0) {

        *x1 = (-b + sqrt(d))/(2 * a);
        *x2 = (-b - sqrt(d))/(2 * a);
        return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Функция для распечатки коэффициентов
void printCoefs(double coefs[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE][3]) {

    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {

        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

            printf("%lf ", coefs[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

// Вывести решения в файл
void createReport(const char* fileName, double coefs[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE][3]) {

    int i;
    double twoRootsEq[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE][2];
    double oneRootEq[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE][1];
    int countOfEqWithNoRoots = 0,
        countOfEqWithOneRoot = 0,
        countOfEqWithTwoRoots = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {

        double x1, x2;
        int rootsCount = findRoots(coefs[i][0], coefs[i][1], coefs[i][2], &x1, &x2);
        if (rootsCount == 0) {

            countOfEqWithNoRoots++;
        } else if (rootsCount == 1) {

            oneRootEq[countOfEqWithOneRoot][0] = x1;
            countOfEqWithOneRoot++;
        } else {

            twoRootsEq[countOfEqWithTwoRoots][0] = x1;
            twoRootsEq[countOfEqWithTwoRoots][1] = x2;
            countOfEqWithTwoRoots++;
        }
    }
    FILE* f = fopen(fileName, "wb");
    if (f) {

        fwrite(&countOfEqWithTwoRoots, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        fwrite(&countOfEqWithOneRoot, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        fwrite(&countOfEqWithNoRoots, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        if (countOfEqWithTwoRoots > 0) {

            fwrite(twoRootsEq, sizeof(double), countOfEqWithTwoRoots * 2, f);
        }
        if (countOfEqWithOneRoot > 0) {

            fwrite(oneRootEq, sizeof(double), countOfEqWithOneRoot * 1, f);
        }
        fclose(f);
    }
}

// Распечатать решения из файла
void printReportFromFile(const char* fileName) {

    FILE* f = fopen(fileName, "rb");
    if (f) {

        double twoRootsEq[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE][2];
        double oneRootEq[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE][1];
        int countOfEqWithNoRoots = 0,
            countOfEqWithOneRoot = 0,
            countOfEqWithTwoRoots = 0;
        fread(&countOfEqWithTwoRoots, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        fread(&countOfEqWithOneRoot, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        fread(&countOfEqWithNoRoots, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        if (countOfEqWithTwoRoots > 0) {

            fread(twoRootsEq, sizeof(double), countOfEqWithTwoRoots * 2, f);
        }
        if (countOfEqWithOneRoot > 0) {

            fread(oneRootEq, sizeof(double), countOfEqWithOneRoot * 1, f);
        }
        fclose(f);
        printf("2 roots count: %d, 1 root count: %d, no roots count: %d\n", countOfEqWithTwoRoots, countOfEqWithOneRoot, countOfEqWithNoRoots);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < countOfEqWithTwoRoots; i++) {

            printf("%lf %lf\n", twoRootsEq[i][0], twoRootsEq[i][1]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < countOfEqWithOneRoot; i++) {

            printf("%lf\n", oneRootEq[i][0]);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    double coefs[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE][3] = {{1.23, 34.5, 34.2}, {1.23, 343.345, 344.2}, {123.23, 34.55, 34.2}, {12.23, 34.5, 34.2}, {7.243, 341.5, 84.2}}; // Коэффициенты уравнений для примера
    writeCoefsToFile("input.txt", coefs);
    readCoefsFromFile("input.txt", coefs);
    printCoefs(coefs);
    createReport("output.txt", coefs);
    printReportFromFile("output.txt");
    return 0;
}
```